# Deriving and gaining intuition for the equation for the index of refraction $n = \sqrt{\mu_r\epsilon_r}$

Tags: electromagnetism, optics, electromagnetic-radiation, refraction

I've come across the equation in the title.  It relates the [index of refraction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Refractive_index) of a substance to the square root of the product of the relative permittivity and the relative permeability at whatever wavelength the n will apply to.  This seems like a reasonable enough equation as both variables have close ties to electromagnetism, but I would like to have a deeper understanding of the equation.

Can anyone provide a proof or a logical, intuitive explanation of this equation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's the logic (well a particular rendition):

1. Recall that $n$ is defined as the ratio of the speed of light $c$ in vacuum to the speed of light $v$ in the given medium;
   \begin{align}
     n = \frac{c}{v}
   \end{align}
2. Note that in a linear medium, Maxwell's equations are exactly the same as in vacuum, except $\mu_0$ and $\epsilon_0$ are replaced by $\mu$ and $\epsilon$.
3. It follows from 2 that each component of the electric and magnetic fields satisfies the three-dimensional wave equation
   \begin{align}
     \nabla^2\phi = \frac{1}{v^2}\frac{\partial^2\phi}{\partial t^2}
   \end{align}
   with
   \begin{align}
     v = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\epsilon\mu}}
   \end{align}
4. Combine steps 1 and 3, and recall that the speed of light in vacuum is
   \begin{align}
     c = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\epsilon_0\mu_0}}
   \end{align}
   to obtain
   \begin{align}
     n = \sqrt{\frac{\epsilon\mu}{\epsilon_0\mu_0}} = \sqrt{\epsilon_r\mu_r}
   \end{align}

Comment: Right, but I'd say that to develop an "intuition" for this you have to spend some time focusing on why *"in a linear medium, Maxwell's equations are exactly the same as in vacuum, except $\mu_0$ and $\epsilon_0$ are replaced by $\mu$ and $\epsilon$."*. Any upper division E&M course or text should cover it in exhaustive detail.

Comment: @dmckee That's a good point.  Maybe I'll add an addendum at some points that says a few words on that.

Comment: @joshphysics In solid state physics, the relative permeability is always dropped out from your last equation when deriving and establishing a relation between refractive index and dielectric constant. Is there a reason for this please?